# Updating Nested Models with single Form MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Entity called Devices and an Entity Called DeviceSerials.  A single device can have 1 or More serial numbers.  I want to create a Create and Edit View for a device that allows the addition of one or more serial numbers.  The key here is i want the Device model passed back to the Device controller and that controller create or update the device AND serial numbers

I created an Editor Template for DeviceSerials and called this template in my Edit and Create View using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceSerials)
```

My Create Action (GET) for the Device

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Device device = new Device();

        DeviceSerial deviceserial = new DeviceSerial();
        device.DeviceSerials.Add(deviceserial);

        return View(device);
    }
```

My Create Action (POST) for the Device

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Device device)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Devices.AddObject(device);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Site", new { id = device.SiteId });  
        }


        return View(device);
    }
```

When I click the create button i get the following error

*The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.*

That being said i did research and found two solutions

The first solution fixed my Create Action but my Edit action still gave me the same error

Solution #1:  Modify the Create (POST) Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="DeviceSerials")]Device device)
    {


        TryUpdateModel(device.DeviceSerials, "DeviceSerials");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Devices.AddObject(device);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Site", new { id = device.SiteId });  
        }
       return View(device);
    }
```

Solution #2:  Implement a custom Model Binder (which i could not get working)

[Link to Solution](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Binding-Model-Graphs-with-ASPNETMVC.aspx)

Can anyone recomend the best way to acomplish what I am trying to do?